# Rails has_many, habtm SQL join not returning any results

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, scope, associations

I'm trying to get an array of customers who have purchase at least two items. The associations are pretty simple, but I'm just not getting any results in my test. Maybe another set of eyes can see what I'm missing.

```
# customer.rb
class Customer < Person
  has_many :orders, foreign_key: 'person_id'
  has_many :items, through: :orders


  # This is what I'm needing help with:
  def self.min_2_orders
    joins(:items).group('items_orders.item_id').having('COUNT(items_orders.item_id) >= ?', 2)
  end
end
```

-

```
# order.rb
class Order < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :customer, foreign_key: 'person_id'
  has_and_belongs_to_many :items
end
```

-

```
# item.rb
class Item < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_and_belongs_to_many :orders
end
```

-

```
# customer_spec.rb
it "finds customers who have ordered a min of 2 items" do
  @order1, @order2  = FactoryGirl.create_list(:order, 2) #returns 2 created orders

  @order2.items << FactoryGirl.create_list(:item, 2) #returns 2 created items

  @customer1  = @order2.customer
  @customer2  = @order1.customer

  ## Debug tests
    Order.count.should            == 2 #pass
    Customer.count.should         == 2 #pass
    Item.count.should             == 2 #pass
    @order_min.items.count.should == 2 #pass
    @customer1.items.count.should == 2 #pass

    puts Order.all.to_yaml    # debug. see below
    puts Customer.all.to_yaml # debug. see below
    puts Item.all.to_yaml     # debug. see below
  # End debugging

  # The final test
  Customer.min_2_orders.should == [@customer1]  # FAIL. returns []
end
```

Here are the debugging logs (the sql query, and the YAML db data):

```
"SELECT 'people'.* FROM 'people'
  INNER JOIN 'orders' ON 'orders'.'person_id' = 'people'.'id'
  INNER JOIN 'items_orders' ON 'items_orders'.'order_id' = 'orders'.'id'
  INNER JOIN 'items' ON 'items'.'id' = 'items_orders'.'item_id'
WHERE 'people'.'type' IN ('Customer')
  GROUP BY items_orders.item_id
  HAVING COUNT(items_orders.item_id) >= 2"

---
- !ruby/object:Order
  attributes:
    id: 1
    person_id: 1
    created_at: 2013-06-18 16:42:17.558683000 Z
    updated_at: 2013-09-17 16:42:17.597082000 Z
- !ruby/object:Order
  attributes:
    id: 2
    person_id: 2
    created_at: 2013-09-17 16:42:17.600267000 Z
    updated_at: 2013-09-17 16:42:17.600267000 Z
---
- !ruby/object:Customer
  attributes:
    id: 1
    first_name: Wes
    type: Customer
    created_at: 2013-09-17 16:42:17.565677000 Z
    updated_at: 2013-09-17 16:42:17.565677000 Z
- !ruby/object:Customer
  attributes:
    id: 2
    first_name: Wes
    type: Customer
    created_at: 2013-09-17 16:42:17.599013000 Z
    updated_at: 2013-09-17 16:42:17.599013000 Z
---
- !ruby/object:Item
  attributes:
    id: 1
    name: Product 1
    created_at: 2013-09-17 16:42:17.632347000 Z
    updated_at: 2013-09-17 16:42:17.632347000 Z
- !ruby/object:Item
  attributes:
    id: 2
    name: Product 2
    created_at: 2013-09-17 16:42:17.633920000 Z
    updated_at: 2013-09-17 16:42:17.633920000 Z
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're grouping by `item_id`, you're only getting one record per `item_id`, so you'll never have `count(item_id)` greater than one. You should be grouping by `people.id`.

On a related point, MySQL is unique in that:

> MySQL extends the use of GROUP BY so that the select list can refer to
>   nonaggregated columns not named in the GROUP BY clause

as documented in http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/group-by-extensions.html

Comment: Thank you so much for your response. You were absolutely right in stating that grouping by `item_id` is wrong, which opened up my eyes to the problem. I needed to group by `order_id` instead. You led me right to the problem, thanks again Peter! If I could, I would upvote you twice.

Comment: Your welcome, but if you group by `order_id`, I think you'll get people who placed orders with more than two items, but won't get (for example) people who only placed two orders of one item each.

Comment: Ok I see. I was thinking to group in the `items_orders` table the whole time, which wouldn't allow me to group by `person_id` since it didn't exist. I changed the group clause to `orders.person_id` and the test passes perfectly. Thanks again :)